# Android Studio Not opening in Mac OS Mojave

Tags: macos, android-studio, macos-mojave

I have updated my Mac To Mojave . I then downloaded and installed android studio . Every time I open it it closes immediately giving this as an error response.

This is the error I receive:
[image: This is the error I encountered]

Any solutions to this or should I downgrade back to High Sierra?

Comment: I found a Solution to this problem anyway .

Comment: Could you please mention what the solution you found was? So that this can help other people who may be having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

This seems that Android Studio wants to use some port but any of these port are used by other process.

In my Android Studio on Linux, I just found that Android Studio used port 63342 8700 6942 and 43993. Try looking for any process using these port and kill them if necessary.

However I don't know what (the reason, and the usage) these ports are used in Android Studio for, and how to specify the port number.

**Update**: In `Settings` I found 63342 is the debug port (`Build, Execution, Deployment` -> `Debugger` -> `Built-in Server`). Using `curl`, I found 8700 is reset by remote, 6942 returns `'~/.AndroidStudio3.2/config'~/.AndroidStudio3.2/system---`, 43993 is empty.

Comment: How do I find my ports in Mac OS?